# Deploy WebApi on Plesk

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webapi, plesk

I am encountering a problem while deploying my web API application on Plesk panel in a Windows hosting environment.  My appsettings.json file looks like this:  `{ "dbConnectionString": "Data Source=.\\MSSQLSERVER2019;Initial Catalog=<DataBaseName>;User ID=<UserName>;Password=<Password>" }`  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <configuration>  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">  <system.webServer>  <handlers>  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />  </handlers>  <aspNetCore processPath=".\AppName.RestApi.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />  </system.webServer>  </location>  </configuration>`  I am encountering a 503 error. I tried changing the hosting model to outofprocess, but it resulted in a 502.5 error.

Comment: ensure the .NET `X` hosting bundle is installed at the server where `X` is your target framework version. Then, after deploy restart the IIS from dedicated IIS page. (sometimes needs to be stopped completely, then deploy, and then re-run it again).

Comment: i found problem. i figured out that .net version on host is version 7 but my project built with version 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found problem. i figured out that .net version on host is version 7 but my project built with version 8.

so i have to downgrade my project.